# Question on what maximum means in the phrase "maximum number of independent generalized $\lambda$-eigenvectors"

Tags: linear-algebra, generalized-eigenvector

I was studying generalized eigenvalues, and I read the following property of the algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$: the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ is the **maximum** number of linearly independent generalized $\lambda$-eigenvectors.

My question is on the use of the word "maximum". Is this saying that that the number of linearly independent generalized $\lambda$-eigenvectors can be **at most** the algebraic multiplicity, or is it saying that it has **exactly** this number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that it is possible to construct a set of linearly independent eigenvectors with size equal to the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue, but not more than it. You can always construct a set with *fewer* linearly independent eigenvectors, because all you do is take that maximal set and remove some of them.